# Place a CD packaging measurement PDF file into Adobe InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, packaging

i need to work on a cd packaging layout. i thought i can just open the pdf file with the basic layout in adobe indesign, so i can drop words and images on it. but that doesnt seem to work. if i 'place' the file in a new layer, it appears. but the quality is oh so bad.

here is the pdf file i need to work with...
http://www.appmulti.ch/website/download_cd_dvd/Kartonhuelle_Schlitz-fuer-1CD_6seitig_CDmittig.pdf

can anybody help me ? i'm new with the software.

thanks, rouven

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate to this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8655/why-are-imported-pdfs-blurry-in-indesign

Answer (score 3):

Select the pdf object and right click - display performance - high quality display.

Answer (score 1):

In-design is great for page layout (for books, leaflets and magazines) - but for packaging and more intricate (die-cut) shapes, you would be much better using illustrator.

You will be able to import the pdf and use vector shapes to help you position images acurately.

(In-design is a habit in the media industry due to historical page work and automation, but the tools in illutrator are much more suited to the packaging workflow)

Answer (score -2):

You can also natively convert the PDF into a layered InDesign layout with for example, Markzware's [PDF2DTP](http://www.markzware.com/products/pdf2dtp). If you just need to layout some text on top of the current design, and if that design is acceptable, then the answer from @Rick is perfect.

Take care,
David
of Markzware (we make PDF2DTP for full disclosure)